# How to move Wordpress theme files into a subfolder without breaking the theme?

Tags: themes, filesystem

I've been coding a Wordpress theme using OOP PHP, node.js and Webpack, and between classes, node_modules, configuration files and Wordpress template files my theme's directory has become a bit messy...

Is there an easy way to move the theme's template files to an `app` subfolder without breaking the theme?

(I've found a similar question but it was asked in 2011, so hopefully something came up over time).

Comment: you mean you want to move the files and the theme will still continue to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box WP relies on Template Hierarchy to resolve and load template. The default assumption is that (most) template *are* in the root of the theme and follow the naming conventions.

Placing template files elsewhere essentially requires rebuilding Template Hierarchy in your code with different assumptions. This used to be crazy inconvenient, but WP 4.7 introduced [`{$type}_template_hierarchy`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template_hierarchy/) hook, which makes it significantly easier.

As a personal aside I think native WP template simply doesn't scale meaningfully to complex use cases. If there are enough templates to clutter the directory, then I would move to a different template engine (such as Twig) altogether. Of course that is hardly mainstream technique in WP development.

I have an [example of template hierarchy override](https://github.com/Rarst/meadow/blob/master/php/class-type-template-hierarchy.php) in my Meadow project for Twig integration, but same works for just changing up logic for PHP templates.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer! I googled the `{$type}_template_hierarchy ` hook and found this code sample [link] (https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/6yh1rv/is_it_possible_to_change_the_wordpress_theme/) on Reddit (bottom of the page) made specifically for Wordpress and which is working for me, in part. What's not working are the custom functions that replace get_header, get_sidebar and get_footer. I noticed header, sidebar and footer are also missing from your Twig class, so I was wondering if you could give any help with those as well? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! The whole code sample is actually working for me, so I guess I'm done. And thank you for putting me on the right way.